# DRF - Djoser returns Unauthorized for all the requests

Tags: django-rest-framework, djoser

I am using Djoser Python package to create an authentication for my app.

As stated in documentation I have updated `settings.py` as shown below -

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
}
```

Also I have added `permission_class` in `APIView`

permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

I am able to obtain the `refresh` and `access` token with credentials -

```
{
    "refresh": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImV4cCI6MTU4NjI1MDYyOCwianRpIjoiZmU5MjA0NzE2NWIwNGNjYmE5YzgzMWYwMDY5Njk4NzQiLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxfQ.I-IPEVrMchQWfGKv80x8pcIMHkEoMlUci7eRZGKjzOA",
    "access": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNTg2MTY0NTI4LCJqdGkiOiI4NGVlMmQ1OWUzYTI0MWU5OGJhNmQyMDBlNTc5NjQ5YSIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjF9.4InHnERd9u7nt8-iaNjt08Fd9169-VVAIYgBGa08euE"
}
```

But when I try to send the POST request using the same `access` token from postman I get this error -

```
{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

Here are the screenshot of the postman request -

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue here is with the authentication header provided to Django Rest Framework.

You are providing an authentication header as :

```
'Authorization': 'Bearer XXXXXXXX'
```

When DRF Token Authentication requires:

```
'Authorization': 'Token XXXXXXXX'
```

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication

Use the suggested Header above or subclass the TokenAuthentication to support Bearer keyword:

https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/commit/ffdac0d93619b7ec6039b94ce0e563f0330faeb1